# Match separate values across two sheets and print out yes or no

Tags: excel

Sheet 1:

[image]

Sheet 2(Ideal Result):

[image]

Basically, what I am trying to do is match the ID first, then find if that person played some kind of sports in that month (from sheet1). If yes, print “Yes” below the corresponding month in the sheet 2, if no, then print out “No” in the sheet2.

I understand if I create a helper column in sheet 1 (let’s say I insert a column before Col A, then the helper col become the new col A, and the original col A become now Col B) and in the helper column (A), I concatenate values in Column B (ID) and E (month) of sheet 1 (e.g. 10001Jan). Then, go to sheet 2, and use the formula `=IFNA(IF(MATCH(CONCAT($A$2,B$1),'Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$1000,0),"Yes","No"),"No")`

The problem would be solved.

But I was wondering, can I solve the issue without creating a helper column (no VBA either)? Or is this the type of scenario where I absolutely need to use VBA or helper column? Any hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A:$A,$A2,Sheet1!$D:$D,B$1),"Yes","No")
```